# Problem writing custom PCI driver with QEMU

Tags: linux, drivers, qemu, pci, interrupt

I want to write a Linux driver that allows me to allocate and handle MSI interrupts. At the moment, the `nvec = pci_alloc_irq_vectors(pdev, 1, nvec, PCI_IRQ_ALL_TYPES)` function is returning -22.

In QEMU, I call `msi_init(&pciechodev->pdev,0,4,true,true,errp)` and it works well. However, when debugging I see that before sending the MSI interrupt the value of `msi_enabled(&edu->pdev)` is 0.

Is this some QEMU bug or some initialization I'm forgetting?